# Converting an example for loop to a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am just beginning to code java, and I found an example of a nested loop which then asks to convert it to a while statement. I am struggling to figure out how to convert it so the output is the same, any help on this would be greatly  appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

         for (int i = j; i < 10; i++) {
           if (i == j) {
             for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
               System.out.print("  ");
             }
           }
           System.out.print(" " + i);
         }
         System.out.println();
       }
```

This is what I have gotten to after trying, but my output is still formatted incorrectly.

```
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 10) { 
        j++;

        int i = j;
        while (i < 10) {
            i++;

            if (i == j) {

                int k = 0;
                    while(k < 10) {
                    k--;

                System.out.print(" ");
                }   
            }
            System.out.print(" " + j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Accidentally left out the first for statement, it is in the body of my text. Sorry for the inconvenience, still getting used to posting questions on here.

Comment: Fixed that for you, no worries.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Think of it like this. The first part of the for loop is an initialization. That can go just before the `while`. The second part is a condition. That goes as the condition for the `while`. The last part is an increment. That goes just before the loop ends. Try to do it this way, and if you can't figure it out come back and ask.

Comment: `int j=0; while(j < 10) { ... ++j;}` simply extract the incrementing variables outside the while statement and increment them inside

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I have added what I thought was correct but my output is still formatted incorrectly to the example, any way fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close!

1.`while(k<10) should be`while(k< j)`  (Also it should be k++ not k--)

2. Move the increments to the bottom of the loops instead of at the top.
3. In the `while(k<j)` loop you should print out two spaces instead of one.

code:

```
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 10) { 


            int i = j;
            while (i < 10) {


                if (i == j) {

                    int k = 0;
                    while(k < j) {

                        System.out.print("  ");
                        k++;
                    }   
                }
                System.out.print(" " + i);
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            j++;
        }
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        4 5 6 7 8 9
          5 6 7 8 9
            6 7 8 9
              7 8 9
                8 9
                  9
```

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated!